# MAMORIOはどうやって位置情報を特定しているのか

Tags: gps

MAMORIO : https://mamorio.jp/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImM3wr8fn1gIVyAcqCh2FlgMSEAAYASAAEgKBXvD_BwE

仕組みとしては、
持ち主AはBluetoothを搭載したタグを持ち歩き、紛失した場合、
他のMAMORIOアプリをinstallしており、BluetoothがONになっている端末Bがそばを通った際、
Bには通知せず、AにMAMORIOの現在の位置情報を表示するものなのですが、
公式の説明で、MAMORIO自体にはGPSは搭載していないとのことで、
携帯端末もBluetoothさえONになっていれば使用できるため、
位置情報は何からどのように取得しているのでしょうか？

携帯端末はGPSをONにしていなくても位置情報を取得できるのでしょうか？

※それなりに高精度で検出されます。

※追記
結論は出ましたが、誤解があるようなので追記いたします。

GPSを搭載していないのはMAMORIO本体です。https://support.mamorio.jp/hc/ja/articles/115005335867-GPS%E3%81%AF%E6%90%AD%E8%BC%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-

MAMORIO持ち主をAさん、MAMORIOをA`
他のユーザーをBさん
とします。

AさんがA`を紛失したとき、BさんがBluetooth圏内に入ると、Aさん宛にBさんの位置情報が送信されますが、このときBさんはGPSを切っていても、正しくAさんに位置情報が送信されます。
そのため、BさんのスマホはGPSを発信していないので、
どういった方法で「GPSを無効にしているBさんの」位置情報を取得していると思われますか、という質問でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

携帯端末での位置情報の取得に関してはGPSの他に「携帯電話の基地局」や「Wi-Fiのアクセスポイント」の情報を元に測位する仕組みがあります。

参考：
http://www.dreamhive.co.jp/201410/2688
http://www.appbank.net/2013/02/24/iphone-news/552221.php

MAMORIOの仕組みは公式ブログでも紹介されています。
[MAMORIO BLOG - MAMORIOの仕組みって？](http://blog.mamorio.jp/post/146286234841/mamorio%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E7%B5%84%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6)
[MAMORIO BLOG - 「みんなで探す」機能って何？](http://blog.mamorio.jp/post/146531920854/%E3%81%BF%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A7%E6%8E%A2%E3%81%99%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E4%BD%95)

Answer (score 0):

> 携帯端末もBluetoothさえONになっていれば使用できるため、

これが誤解なのでは。

これは単にデバイス(タグ)とスマートフォンなどの間の通信のことを言っているのであって、トラッキングで参照される位置情報はスマートフォンの一般的な位置情報(GPS、WiFi、基地局ベース)だと思います。

少なくとも製品情報を見た範囲ではGPSなどを使用せずに位置情報を取得しているというような記載はありませんでした。

Comment: 検証までしているので誤解ではありませんが、基地局ベースという方法もあるんですね、勉強になりました。

Comment: 検証というのは、位置情報の取得機能(GPSではなく)を無効にしても位置情報が取得できたと言うことでしょうか。